# IBM PCF agent returns 3506 error while inquiring channel status

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

There are two *inactive* channels in my mq named SYS1.SC and SYS2.SC with "Server-connection" type, I am trying to get their status using the code below:

```java
queueManage = new MQQueueManager(name);
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
PCFMessage reqChStatus = new PCFMessage();
reqChStatus.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "*");
reqChStatus.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_ATTRS, 
         new int[] {
             MQConstants.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME,
             MQConstants.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS
         });
PCFMessage[] resp = agent.send(reqChStatus);
```

And i got exception on "agent.send(msg)" with message:
***PCFException: MQJE001: Completition code '2', Reason '3065'***
I expect it returns an empty message array if channels is inactive, so can someone help me with this, please.

Comment: This looks normal for what you described: [3065 (0BF9) (RC3065): MQRCCF_CHL_STATUS_NOT_FOUND](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q046620_.html), the lack of channel status means it is INACTIVE.  Every other status would be returned,  for example RUNNING or STOPPED.

Comment: Agree with @JoshMc above comment. If your channel (of any type) is inactive, this means it has no status to be returned. You will see the same behaviour if you try the `runmqsc` equivalent command, `DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*)`